# Titanium Appceleratory Alloy and Regex: Unable to delete characters in textfield with keypad

Tags: regex, titanium, textfield, appcelerator

This function:

```
function maskPhoneNumber( phoneNumber ){
//assure that it is a string
var stringyPhone = String( phoneNumber );

//refresh the number by stripping it of odd characters
stringyPhone = stringyPhone.replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' );

//return only the first 11 digits (if it starts with a 1)
if( stringyPhone.first(1) == 1 ){
    stringyPhone = stringyPhone.first( 11 );    
}else{
    stringyPhone = stringyPhone.first( 10 );
}

stringyPhone = stringyPhone.replace( /^([1]?)(\d{1,3})/, "$1 ($2) " );
stringyPhone = stringyPhone.replace( /(\d{3})(\d{1,4})$/, "$1-$2" );

return stringyPhone;
}
```

Is called here:

```
//on change of the phone number
//mask it and set the value of the form to the masked value
$.loginPhone.addEventListener( 'change', function( event ){
$.loginPhone.setValue( maskPhoneNumber( $.loginPhone.getValue() ) );
} );
```

And it masks quite well on the way up (typing in produces "1 (555) 555-5555)" however there is a strange bug where it stops deleting on the way down (backspacing through the textfield hangs at "1 (555) ").

Is this a regEx error on my part, or am I missing something else? Anyone wiser out there have an idea?

Comment: You're problem is `.replace(/^([1]?)(\d{1,3})/, "$1 ($2) ")`. Every time you backspace to `1 (555)`, it will replace the space you just removed: `1 (555) `.